# Link between topological dimension and Hamel (algebraic) dimension of a vector space

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis, paracompactness

I was wondering if there is a link between this two dimension definitions in the case of a Topological Vector Space in fact I know that sometimes topological dimension coincides with other notions of dimension.

Morover are there interesting results about covering properties of TVS (such as paracompactness, refinements and so on) ?

Comment: Which definition of topological dimension do you use?

Comment: I think the one I know is the Lebesgue dimension of a space: The covering dimension of a topological space X is defined to be the minimum value of n, such that every open cover C of X has an open refinement with ply n + 1 or below. If no such minimal n exists, the space is said to be of infinite covering dimension. The ply or order of a cover is the smallest number n (if it exists) such that each point of the space belongs to at most n sets in the cover.  (WIkipedia)

Comment: A TVS need not be normal, let alone paracompact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various concepts of dimension for topological spcaes, e.g. covering dimension, small inductive dimension, large inductive dimension. All these take values in
$\{0,1,2,\dots \} \cup \{ \infty \}$.

For algebraically finite-dimensional TVSs their algebraic dimension equals their topological dimension. This is not trivial, but well-known.

Given this result, you see that a TVS is algebraically infinite-dimensional iff it is topologically infinite-dimensional.

An algebraically infinite-dimensional TVS $E$ contains $n$-dimensional linear subspaces for all $n$, and these have topological dimension $n$. Since topological dimension is monotone (i.e. $X \subset Y$ implies $\dim X \le \dim Y$), $E$ cannot be topologically finite-dimensional.

The converse is obvious because we already know that an algebraically finite-dimensional TVS is also topologically finite-dimensional.

Comment: It was a typo. TVS is correct. @Xander

Comment: @Xander And this typo allows to make a guess concerning my mother tongue...